# How to convert custom init function from ObjC to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I convert the code for this class to Swift?

## .h file

```
@interface SARCoordinate : NSObject 
 @property(nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
 -(instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
  @end
```

## .m file

```
#import "SARCoordinate.h"
@implementation SARCoordinate

-(instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    self = [super init];
    self.coordinate = coordinate;
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?

Comment: i want to write this code into swift.

Comment: Why didn't you post what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this :

```
var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
 // your init method
 init (2Dcoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
  coordinate = 2Dcoordinate
 }
 //required init method 
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: its not working for me . please check the following method in nsobject class it shows an error in first line -" use of undeclare  type "

Comment: it is working fine for me ..have you imported foundation and can you be clear about the error as i have been using it correctly

Comment: please import CoreLocation

Comment: what about the  return value

Comment: while creating the object using init you can store it using let or var therefore you can use it furthur...:)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this:

```
var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D 

    func initWithCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> instancetype{
      super.init() 
      self.coordinate = coordinate
      return self
    }
```

Comment: nsobject class not taking  CLLocationCoordinate2D object .

Comment: you should be clear on what you are trying to achieve rather than asking people to convert code. What is the purpose of what you are doing is an important part of the question.

Comment: have to make a object class in swift same as the above i posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

Below code might be help you.

```
   import CoreLocation

    class YOURCLASSNAME: NSObject {
        var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
        init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            self.coordinate = coordinate
            super.init()
        }
        convenience override init() {
            self.init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(100.00, 100)) // calls above mentioned controller with default name
        }
    }
```

Please find more on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306) link.